# How do I use soft body and the ocean modifier to make a random screensaver?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, soft-body, ocean-simulation

I am a noob when it comes to the blender game engine, in fact blender in general, however I did find an amazingly simple cool thing to do with a the soft body physics in Blender and the ocean modifier.  So I made the animation below and thought to myself, "Hey, I wonder if I can make a screensaver out of this."  So I looked up a tutorial on makingh a screensaver and found I had to use the blender game engine and make a .exe file then save it has an .scr, but that's not my problem.  I have looked up a lot of tutorials and I can't find a straight answer, but it feels like they are all pointing towards this is currently impossible.  However instead of just scrapping the project, I decided to look for the wonderful people of the internet's advice.  Can you recreate this in blender game as a .exe file and still have it be randomized?  Also, if you can how do I reset the screensaver when the cube hits the plane at the bottom?

Apologies for my long windedness.

Edit: Fixed the links, my bad :/

General idea animation:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5WX5WPaU3pHZF9yVXR1MmIxMnc&authuser=0

Blender file:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5WX5WPaU3pHcUhlTDdCUkJ5ZGs&authuser=0
Pasteall:  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33679

Ignore the other objects in the second layer, I was going to figure out how to add more stuff bouncing around and adding an empty to spawn objects at random so I didn't have to reset the program.

Comment: I can not access the files, Google tells me that I do not have the necessary permissions. Please make sure to make them public.

Comment: Try uploading the .blend files to [pasteall.org](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) instead of Google Drive

Comment: I just uploaded the blend file to pasteall.org